# Azure CDN cached content refresh depending on change on origin azure blob storage

Tags: azure, caching, azure-blob-storage, content-delivery-network

If origin of CDN endpoint is in azure blob storage is there any option in blob storage to refresh the cached content in CDN whenever there is change in specific endpoints in origin blob storage.
TTL purges the whole thing and it is time based rather then origin content update based.

At the moment every time I am changing the content of specific endpoints in origin blob storage I have to di equivalent purge action for it's CDN counterpart. Just think something should be available in azure to make this work, as origin can sometime be manually changed and the cached CDN content won't get refreshed.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do it automatically. As the docs say "Azure CDN edge nodes will cache assets until the asset's time-to-live (TTL) expires. The best practice to make sure your users always obtain the latest copy of your assets is to version your assets for each update and publish them as new URLs. CDN will immediately retrieve the new assets for the next client requests."

Comment: Yeah, but versioning of content is not always possible, usually people overwrite the files in blob and azure blob allows it. It is not restricted to retire the previous URI and create new URI. In such cases the assumptions will fail in case someone does URI overwrite instead of new URI creation. It also makes sense in content context where history of change in content might not be important at all for use cases.

Comment: Yes, in that case, you should use event-based automation to purge the content. For example with Automation account and Event Grid. Check out this article. https://www.ciraltos.com/purge-azure-cdn-with-event-grid-and-azure-automation/

Comment: Will try this, thanks!